# $X^p-p^2X+p\in \Bbb Q[X]$ has no roots in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n},\sqrt[n]{m})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $1<m,n<p$, where $p$ is a prime number.

We want to prove that the polynomial 
$$f(X):=X^p-p^2X+p\in \Bbb Q[X]$$
has no roots in the field $E:=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n},\sqrt[n]{m})$.

*My thought.* Suppose on the contrary that $\alpha \in E$ is a root of this $f(X)$ inside $E$. Then, $f(\alpha)=0.$ Now, consider the extension of fields
$$[E:\Bbb Q]=[E:\Bbb Q(\alpha)][\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q].$$
By the Eisenstein's Criterion, $f$ is irreducible, monic and with root the element $\alpha$, so $m_{(\alpha,\Bbb Q)}=f$. Hence, $\deg m_{(\alpha,\Bbb Q)}=[\Bbb Q(\alpha):\Bbb Q]=p$ and therefore $p|[E:\Bbb Q]$. But now I m not sure that is in the correct direction.

Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. Consider now
$$[E:\Bbb Q]=[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n},\sqrt[n]{m}):\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n})] \cdot [\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n}) :\Bbb Q]$$

Since $p| [E:\Bbb Q]$ and $p$ is prime you get that $p|[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n},\sqrt[n]{m}):\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n})]$ or $p| [\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n}) :\Bbb Q]$.

Argue now that
$$[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n},\sqrt[n]{m}):\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n})] \leq n<p \\
 [\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n}) :\Bbb Q] \leq m <p$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Take $g(Χ):=X^n-m\in \Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n})[X]$ and $h(X):=X^m-n \in \Bbb Q[X]$. Then, since $g(\sqrt[n]{m})=0=h(\sqrt[m]{n})=0$, we have that $m_{(\sqrt[n]{m},\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n}))}(X)|g(X),\  m_{(\sqrt[n]{m},\Bbb Q)}(X)|h(X) $. So the degrees are less or equal. If $p|[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n},\sqrt[n]{m}):\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n})] \implies p \leq [\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n},\sqrt[n]{m}):\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n})]$. But then $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n},\sqrt[n]{m}):\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n})]< [\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n},\sqrt[n]{m}):\Bbb Q(\sqrt[m]{n})]$, contradiction, and likewise for the other case. Right?

Comment: @Chris Yes.....